# My object contains multiple instances of itself, should I be concerned?

Tags: php, oop, object, multiple-instances

I have two classes, `Quiz` and `Question`:

```
class Quiz()
{

    public $quiz_id;
    public $quiz_name;

    // Arrays of objects
    public $questions;
    public $personalities;

    function __construct($quiz_id)
    {
        // Sets the basic data of the quiz
        $this->quiz_id = $quiz_id;
        $this->quiz_name = $quiz_name_from_db;
    }

    function LoadQuestions()
    {
        // Get question ids from database

        // Blank array to add questions to 
        $array_of_question_objects = array();

        foreach ($question_from_db AS $question_info)
        {

            // Create Question object, passing this Quiz object 
            $question_object = new Question($question_info["question_id"], $this);

            // Add the question to the array
            $array_of_question_objects += $question_object;

        }

        // Set the array within the Quiz object
        $this->questions = $array_of_question_objects;
    }

    function LoadPersonalities()
    {
        $this->personalities = $array_of_personalty_objects;
    }
}

class Question()
{

    public $question;

    // Quiz object within the question for access to personalities and quiz type
    private $quiz_object;

    function __construct($question_id, $quiz_object)
    {
        // Set the quiz object within the question
        $this->quiz_object;

        // Load the question information from the database and set the values of the class
        $this->question = $question_from_database;
    }


    function ShowQuestion()
    {
        // Show a question on the page and also
        // Loop through all of the personalities

        echo "<div id="question">";


        if ($quiz_object->quiz_type == "personality")
        {
            foreach ($quiz_object->personalities AS $quiz_personality)
            {

                // Show each personality
                echo $quiz_personality;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I need to give my Question objects access to my `Quiz` objects values: `$quiz_type` and `$personalities`.

If I wish to load all questions and with their possible personality outcomes I will use the following code:

```
$quiz_id = 1;

// Create a quiz object
$quiz_object = new Quiz($quiz_id);

// Load the questions in to the Quiz object
$quiz_object->LoadQuestions();

// Load all of the personalities
$quiz_object->LoadPersonalities();

// Show the questions
foreach ($quiz_object->questions AS $question)
{
    // Show the question
    $question->ShowQuestion();
}
```

If I wish to show just one question (and all personality information), I can use the following code:

```
$quiz_id = 1;
$question_id = 40;

// Create a quiz object
$quiz_object = new Quiz($quiz_id);

// Load all of the personalities for the quiz object
$quiz_object->LoadPersonalities();

// Load the question as an object
$question_object = new Question($question_id, $quiz_object);

// Show the HTML for the question
$question_object->ShowQuestion();
```

**I am concerned that each of my Question objects needs information from the Quiz object in order to function**.

When I load all of the Question objects in to my Quiz (using $quiz_object->LoadQuestions), my quiz object essentially contains the question information as well as an instance of **itself** multiple times for each question of the quiz.

So it looks a little bit like

> `Quiz_object` {
>
> ```
> Question_object:
> {
>     question information
>     instance of `Quiz_object`
> }
>
> Question_object:
> {
>     question information
>     instance of `Quiz_object`
> }
>
> Question_object:
> {
>     question information
>     instance of `Quiz_object`
> }
>
> Question_object:
> {
>     question information
>     instance of `Quiz_object`
> }
>
> Question_object:
> {
>     question information
>     instance of `Quiz_object`
> }
> ```
>
> }

So my `Quiz` object is duplicated multiple times within the object.

Should I be concerned about this, or does PHP handle the instance that I pass around as simply a "reference" to the object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even you assign the *same* quiz instance to multiple variables, this must not be an issue at all but can perfectly okay.

Because you have a single instance here, and each variable is a way of accessing *that one* instance, here in your example the questions *know* of which quiz they are part of.

As in your design the questions need to know to which quiz they belong to, this is what you need so it's generally applicable.

It is a standard 1:n relationship:

```
   1:n

quiz:questions
```

Take care that you keep the number of relations to the needed minimum for your application to work.

Comment: I'm a little confused :(.  There's a way to get the Quiz information from my Questions when they are within the Quiz object?

Comment: `new Question($question_id, $quiz_object);` <- at least you pass the quiz into each question, so I'd say yes. :)

Comment: So by the sounds of it, I could pass that object to as many questions as I want and it won't duplicate the values.  It simply has a way of referring to the same object?

Comment: Exactly. This is why you call it object somehow as well. All questions refer to the *same* quiz object. The number of variables does not count.

Answer (score 2):

Do not worry, since version 5 of PHP passing around objects is done by reference.

Comment: **-1** : **wrong**. Since PHP5 objects are passed around by object handlers. Please watch http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxxIXPc9IR8 for additional details.

Comment: tereško is just being annoying, passing by object handles in the end means that the object is not duplicated, and a reference to the object is passed around.

Comment: @JvdBerg how is pointing out, that references and object handlers are different things, "being annoying" ? Please read http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Comment: @tereško being a prick that downvotes for people that try to contribute are not as “knowledgeable” like you is being annoying. Sadly, SO is full of people like you. You must learn to contribute in a constructive way, not with your pedantic attitude.